# Enable default php-fpm on OS X Mavericks

Tags: nginx, php

I have a nginx version 1.6 running on my local machine.

OS X Mavericks comes already with php installed

On typing

```
php -v
php-fpm -v
```

it's showing PHP(5.4.24)

How do I configure the default php-fpm on my computer so that I serve php from nginx server?
I want to use the same version of php without installing a new version of it.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: just start your php-fpm, and configure your nginx to connect to php-fpm.

Comment: sudo /System/Library/StartupItems/php-fpm start

Comment: look here  http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2010/07/12/getting-started-with-nginx-and-php-fpm/

Comment: skip php & php-fpm installation part, just jump to nginx configuration part

Comment: I have nginx configured. Its giving a Bad Gateway 502 error. Moreover php-fpm start is not running. php-fpm is already on path, so I'm just running php-fpm start

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252368/nginx-502-bad-gateway is this helped?

Comment: and more http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Nginx+PHP-FPM+502+Bad+Gateway